# How to apply the schema of one dataframe to another?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I read a file as String and I need to compare it with the table to do some operations.

```
df1 = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,"aa")).toDF("Col1","Col2") // file
df2 = spark.sql("select * from table")
```

So the df1 is from file which has both columns as String whereas the df2 has the schema as Int and String. This is just a sample, I have many columns to select and cant mention each column name. Is there a way to implement the column schema of df2 to df1? Or is it possible to select * from table as String?
Like example,

```
spark.sql("select cast(* as String) from table")
```

Comment: if you are reading from file, use the databricks package . The package automatically infers the schema , moreover you can provide your own schema.

Comment: What and how do you want to compare? give some samples. And also mention what you have tried and whats your difficult part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not really clear **why** are you doing what you are doing, but here it comes.

> whereas the df2 has the schema as Int and String
>
> Is there a way to implement the column schema of df2 to df1?
>
> `spark.sql("select cast(* as String) from table")`

It *appears* you want to map all the columns of `df2` to be of `String` type. Given you don't really know how many columns you have to do the comparison dynamically.

```
val df2 = spark.sql("select * from table")
scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)

// do the casting regardless of the number of columns
val cols = df2.columns.map(c => col(c) cast "string")
val solution = df2.select(cols: _*) // <-- a trick to use the columns
scala> solution.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
```

---

Consider using table operator to create a dataset from `table` table.

> **table(tableName: String): DataFrame** Returns the specified table as a DataFrame.

Your code would then be as follows (which I think would be much easier to understand):

```
val df2 = spark.table("table")
```